# Operation on Sub-exponential Reduction

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request

I have a question concerning the SERF-reducibility of [Impagliazzo, Paturi and Zane](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y951Y9IehqDU16fhmIdLKg9OsClyMrtX/view?usp=drivesdk) and subexponential algorithms.

***My question is:*** is a composition of two SERF reductions  a SERF reduction? Are there a write-up of the proof somewhere?

Little work is [here.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9233/serf-reducibility-and-subexponential-algorithms)

Comment: The answer follows almost directly from the definition. You got 2 families of Turing reductions, can you compose them into a single one? Hint from the paper: SERF-reducibility is transitive,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper you cite in your question it is already mentioned that SERF reductions are transitive, which typically follows from the closure of reductions under composition. Here's a proof:

According to the definition given, a SERF reduction $R$ is a collection of Turing reductions $\{ M_{\epsilon}^{A_{2}} \}_{\epsilon > 0}$ from the problem $A_{1}$ with complexity parameter $m_{1}$ to the problem $A_{2}$ with complexity parameter $m_{2}$ such that the following hold for each $\epsilon > 0$:

1. $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{2}}$ runs in time at most $poly(|x|)2^{\epsilon m_{1}(x)}$.
2. If $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{2}}$ queries $A_{2}$ on input $x'$, then $m_{2}(x') \in O( m_{1}(x) )$ and $|x'| = |x|^{O(1)}$.

The notion of complexity parameter is explained in section 1.1.2 of the paper and simply is a generalization of using the input or solution size to characterize the complexity and/or size of relevant quantities. E.g. for the problem $k$-SAT the complexity parameter could be the number of variables, the number of clauses or the binary length of the SAT expression.

Now, suppose we have $2$ SERF reductions $R_{1}$ from $A_{1}$ with complexity parameter $m_{1}$ to $A_{2}$ with complexity parameter $m_{2}$ and $R_{2}$ from $A_{2}$ to $A_{3}$ with complexity parameter $m_{3}$. We will define the composition in a meaningful way and show that it is also a SERF reduction from $A_{1}$ to $A_{3}$.

The composition of two SERF reductions must also be a collection, where we compose the two Turing reductions for each fixed $\epsilon > 0$.We need to check that the restriction of the definition still hold for each $\epsilon>0$.

To begin with, we can simply compose the two Turing reductions $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{2}}$ and $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{3}}$ to obtain $M_{\epsilon}^{'A_{3}}$. This is possible since Turing reductions are composable. In short, whenever $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{2}}$ queries $A_{2}$ on input $x'$, instead of using the oracle for $A_{2}$ we call $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{3}}$ on input $x'$. It remains only to see if the restrictions are respected:

Restriction 2: Since $R_{2}$ is a SERF reduction we have that each query $x''$ to $A_{3}$ in $M_{\epsilon}^{'A_{3}}$ satisfies $m_{3}(x'') \in O(m_{2}(x'))$ and $|x''| = |x'|^{O(1)}$ where $x'$ is the input to $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{3}}$. Now in turn since $R_{1}$ is a SERF reduction we know that $m_{2}(x') \in O(m_{1}(x))$ and $|x'| = |x|^{O(1)}$. Combining the two we have that $m_{3}(x'') \in O(m_{2}(x')) \in O(m_{1}(x))$ and $|x''| = |x'|^{O(1)} = |x|^{O(1)}$ so the restriction is satisfied.

Restriction 1: $M_{\epsilon}^{'A_{3}}$ may call $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{3}}$ at most once for each running step of $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{2}}$. $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{2}}$ runs in time $poly(|x|)2^{\epsilon m_{1}(x)}$. Each call to $M_{\epsilon}^{A_{3}}$ takes time at most $poly(|x'|)2^{\epsilon m_{2}(x')} = poly(|x|)2^{\epsilon c m_{1}(x)}$ where the equality follows from Restriction 2. Thus the running time in total is at most the product of the two, $poly(|x|)2^{\epsilon m_{1}(x)} * poly(|x|)2^{\epsilon c m_{1}(x)} $ = $poly(|x|)2^{\epsilon (1+c) m_{1}(x)}$  thus the restriction is satisfied.

Since this holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, it follows that the composition of two SERF reductions is also a SERF reduction and thus SERF reductions are transitive.

Comment: Oh, apologies I misread the original paper. This adds an additional complication that the composition created works for $\epsilon' = (1+c) \epsilon$. But since such a TM exists for each $\epsilon > 0$, we end up with a collection for all $\epsilon >0$ as needed.